# mimic a do while logic control to handle rotate problem

Tags: python

I read such a problem in leetcode

> Given an array, rotate the array to the right by *k* steps, where *k* is non-negative.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and k = 3
> Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
> Explanation:
> rotate 1 steps to the right: [7,1,2,3,4,5,6]
> rotate 2 steps to the right: [6,7,1,2,3,4,5]
> rotate 3 steps to the right: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: [-1,-100,3,99] and k = 2
> Output: [3,99,-1,-100]
> Explanation: 
> rotate 1 steps to the right: [99,-1,-100,3]
> rotate 2 steps to the right: [3,99,-1,-100]
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> - Try to come up as many solutions as you can, there are at least 3 different ways to solve this problem.
> - Could you do it in-place with O(1) extra space?

and it's official solution was written in java

[image]

```
public class Solution {
    public void rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
        k = k % nums.length;
        int count = 0;
        for (int start = 0; count < nums.length; start++) {
            int current = start;
            int prev = nums[start];
            do {
                int next = (current + k) % nums.length;
                int temp = nums[next];
                nums[next] = prev;
                prev = temp;
                current = next;
                count++;
            } while (start != current);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to translate it to python

```
class Solution3:
    def rotate(self, nums, k):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        k = k % len(nums)
        count = 0
        start = 0
        while count < len(nums):
            current = start 
            prev = nums[start] #store the value in the position

            while start != current:
                next = (current + k) % len(nums)
                temp = nums[next]
                nums[next] = prev 
                prev = temp #store the value 
                current = next 
                count += 1
```

However, there is not such a logic as `do while`

How could handle such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can simulate the behaviour of `do while` like so

```
while True:
    do_things()
    if not cond:
        break
```

So in your case:

```
while True:
    next = (current + k) % len(nums)
    temp = nums[next]
    nums[next] = prev 
    prev = temp #store the value 
    current = next 
    count += 1

    if start == current:
        break
```

Comment: amazing, thank you. I am surprised that you have 151 scores but be so professional in python. What's book or course are you taking?